# Change/hide div when click on link

Tags: jquery

I have just began JQuery and I have an issue. Here is the code and I'll explain the problem :

```js
var main=function(){
    $('.disp').hide(); // hide information div
    $('h4').on('click',function(){
        var textHTML=$(this).attr('data-info');
        $('.disp').hide("200");
        $('#' + textHTML).slideToggle("300");
    });
};


$(document).ready(main);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div id="displayInfo" class="row">
  <h4 data-info="WEB" class="col-sm-2">WEB</h4>
  <h4 data-info="VBA" class="col-sm-2">VBA</h4>
  <h4 data-info="C" class="col-sm-2">C</h4>
  <h4 data-info="CPP" class="col-sm-2">C++</h4>
  <h4 data-info="Java" class="col-sm-2">Java</h4>
 </div>

 <div id="WEB" class="disp">
  <p><u><strong>WEB</strong></u></p>
  <p><strong>test</strong>, test, <strong>test</strong></p>
  <p><strong>test test test</strong><br/>
   test
  </p>
 </div>
 <div id="VBA" class="disp">
  <p><u><strong>VBA</strong></u></p>
  <p><strong>test</strong>, test, <strong>test</strong></p>
  <p><strong>test test test</strong><br/>
   test
  </p>
 </div>
 <div id="C" class="disp">
  <p><u><strong>C</strong></u></p>
  <p><strong>test</strong>, test, <strong>test</strong></p>
  <p><strong>test test test</strong><br/>
   test
  </p>
 </div>
 <div id="CPP" class="disp">
  <p><u><strong>C++</strong></u></p>
  <p><strong>test</strong>, test, <strong>test</strong></p>
  <p><strong>test test test</strong><br/>
   test
  </p>
 </div>
 <div id="Java" class="disp">
  <p><u><strong>Java</strong></u></p>
  <p><strong>test</strong>, test, <strong>test</strong></p>
  <p><strong>test test test</strong><br/>
   test
  </p>
 </div>

</div>
```

When I click on a programming language, I want to display some informations about it. Which works fine. The problem is that I don't know how to hide the information when I click on the same programming language. I mean if the VBA informations are displayed, I want it to hide when I click again on the VBA name. The `toggle` function works fine BUT if I don't hide the previous information div, the program will display it under.

I just want when I click a programming language to display informations, when I click another name it overwrites the one before and when I click the same name again it hides.

I tried to store variables, add attributs but I can't figure this problem out.

I tried things like addClass() and check if there is the class or else hide it and a lot of if conditions..

(bootstrap doesn't seem to work here)

I also add a jsfiddle if you'd like to try things https://jsfiddle.net/5ujLsssa/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you just need to exclude the clicked element from the logic that hides all the `.disp` elements. You can use `not()` to achieve this:

```js
var main = function() {
  $('.disp').hide();
  
  $('h4').on('click', function() {
    var $target = $('#' + $(this).data('info'));
    $('.disp').not($target).hide("200");
    $target.slideToggle("300");
  });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="displayInfo" class="row">
    <h4 data-info="WEB" class="col-sm-2">WEB</h4>
    <h4 data-info="VBA" class="col-sm-2">VBA</h4>
    <h4 data-info="C" class="col-sm-2">C</h4>
    <h4 data-info="CPP" class="col-sm-2">C++</h4>
    <h4 data-info="Java" class="col-sm-2">Java</h4>
  </div>

  <div id="WEB" class="disp">
    <p><u><strong>WEB</strong></u>
    </p>
    <p><strong>test</strong>, test, <strong>test</strong>
    </p>
    <p><strong>test test test</strong>
      <br/>test
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="VBA" class="disp">
    <p><u><strong>VBA</strong></u>
    </p>
    <p><strong>test</strong>, test, <strong>test</strong>
    </p>
    <p><strong>test test test</strong>
      <br/>test
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="C" class="disp">
    <p><u><strong>C</strong></u>
    </p>
    <p><strong>test</strong>, test, <strong>test</strong>
    </p>
    <p><strong>test test test</strong>
      <br/>test
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="CPP" class="disp">
    <p><u><strong>C++</strong></u>
    </p>
    <p><strong>test</strong>, test, <strong>test</strong>
    </p>
    <p><strong>test test test</strong>
      <br/>test
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="Java" class="disp">
    <p><u><strong>Java</strong></u>
    </p>
    <p><strong>test</strong>, test, <strong>test</strong>
    </p>
    <p><strong>test test test</strong>
      <br/>test
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Also note the use of `data()` over `attr()` to retrieve the `data-info` attribute.

Comment: Well.. that works. Sorry if my question seemed easy but I had no idea of that `not()` attribute.. Thank you very much (I also did not know about the `data()`) (I have to wait before accepting your answer but i'll do it)

Comment: Hi @Rory McCrossan. Here suppose if the div having id="WEB" is displayed and again if I clicked on h4 having data-info="WEB", the corresponding div is hidden. Can you let me know how to prevent this change.

Comment: If you're asking how to prevent the toggle behaviour, change `slideToggle()` to `slideDown()`